# To run a background process that should keep running while moving from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have to do a background process which will perform some operations.. while this operation is running, a user can switch from one activity to another. How can i do this by maintaining the background process to be keep running ? Please reply.
i was using asynctask for this. but when i switch from one activity to another it use to stop the operations which were getting performed at background thread. Please reply

Comment: I may be wrong but when switching activities, don't both activities continue to run you finish one of the activities with a finish? Why not allow your background task to get running in the previous activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform a background task that should run to completion irrespective of which activity is brought to front, you can set up a **service** to achieve this. The Android system assigns a dedicated thread pool to your service which allows tasks executed via the service run independent of the foreground activity of your app.

The Android developer documentation provides a [detailed description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) of this concept.

I had a similar requirement with my app .. Using services did the trick for me :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using service now and it worked out well.:)